# Convert string of months with data into a two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, explode, strtok

Good morning!

I have a string with some number of various months with each month followed by a series of numbers. I need to break that string into a two dimensional array: Months in the first column with columns of numbers after them.

I've worked out some solutions using strtok, explode and a month lookup table. But my solutions seem very cumbersome. I would appreciate an elegant, simple solution that someone with some real coding experience would use. My string and hoped for 2D array result below.

Thank you for your expertise and time!

DEC 14 1938.50 1964.50 1935.75 1959.75 21.75 1960.25 1551405 2751445 MAR 15 1931.00 1956.2 1928.0 1952.0 21.75 1952.50 2244 5495 JUN 15 1920.25 1949.0 1920.25 1945.0 22.00 1945.50 88 350 SEP 15 1925.00 1937.7 1925.00 1937.7 21.75 1938.75 6 204 DEC 15 1935.75 1935.75 1935.75 1935.75 22.00 1932.75 1 212

Ends up being:
DEC 14 1938.50 1964.50 1935.75 1959.75 21.75 1960.25 1551405 2751445
MAR 15 1931.00 1956.2 1928.0 1952.0 21.75 1952.50 2244 5495
etc...

Comment: Which programming language? You're using the `explode` tag, so I assume it's PHP, but you should specify it explicitely.

Comment: Is the number of columns always 10? Or are there sometimes more or less columns?

Comment: Thank you for the reminder lxg! Yes, you are correct. PHP. And there may be more or less rows and columns. But the basic string structure remains the same. A three letter month followed by data. The three letter month codes remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```php
$data = "DEC 14 1938.50 1964.50 1935.75 1959.75 21.75 1960.25 1551405 2751445 MAR 15 1931.00 1956.2 1928.0 1952.0 21.75 1952.50 2244 5495 JUN 15 1920.25 1949.0 1920.25 1945.0 22.00 1945.50 88 350 SEP 15 1925.00 1937.7 1925.00 1937.7 21.75 1938.75 6 204 DEC 15 1935.75 1935.75 1935.75 1935.75 22.00 1932.75 1 212";

$dataArray = preg_split('|\s+|', $data);
$table = array();
$idx = -1; // -1 because the first array index should be 0

foreach ($dataArray as $elem)
{
    if (preg_match('|^[A-Z]{3}$|', $elem))
    {
        $table[++$idx] = array('month' => $elem, 'values' => array());
    }
    elseif (isset($table[$idx])) // in case the first word is not a month
    {
        $table[$idx]['values'][] = $elem;
    }
}
```

This gives the following result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => DEC
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14
                    [1] => 1938.50
                    [2] => 1964.50
                    [3] => 1935.75
                    [4] => 1959.75
                    [5] => 21.75
                    [6] => 1960.25
                    [7] => 1551405
                    [8] => 2751445
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => MAR
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 15
                    [1] => 1931.00
                    [2] => 1956.2
                    [3] => 1928.0
                    [4] => 1952.0
                    [5] => 21.75
                    [6] => 1952.50
                    [7] => 2244
                    [8] => 5495
                )

        )

    …
)
```

Note: A simpler array structure, using the month as key, would not work, because some of the months appear several times (e.g. `DEC`), and values would be overwritten.

Comment: WOW! Thank you lxg. That's brilliant. I did not know you could name  regular expressions and use them like that. 

Unfortunately, the line: $table = []; yields a php error, "unexpected ["  I am assuming that is the declaration for the array. I've tried several alternatives but either I get an error on that line or the $table[++$idx]... line. 

What am I missing?
Thank you again for your guidance and expertise :)

Comment: Right, that's an alternative PHP >= 5.4 notation for arrays. I've rewritten it to the classical notation, please try again.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. It still errors out on the $table[++$idx]... line. So I tried: $table[] = array(); and also errored out. But I ran the code anyway and it worked. Both ways! So it looks like the error is being thrown in my old PHPEdit editor. Ouch! And, your code works also as shown originally. Unexpected. I suppose at this point, any suggestion for an open source php editor would be appreciated. ;)  Thank you again lgx for the expertly done code and education besides.

Comment: What error message do you get? Which PHP version are you using?